# Scale to specific part of android ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, scale

I can scale image which is in a `RelativeLayout` and It will fit to that `RelativeLayout`. The `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` methods, set the scale to center of the image. But how can I zoom or scale to specific coordinate of Image? I tried `setX` and `setY` methods too, but they don't work when image is scaled.

Comment: Is the image set as background in the RelativeLayout or is it an ImageView within RelativeLayout?

Comment: @VivekRK It's an ImageView within RelativeLayout